# Weird behaviour when uploading multiple files using AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have an ASP MVC 4 project which uses AngularJS. There's a form, containing both data and an arbitrary number of files, which needs to be posted to the server. When I try to send more than one file, ASP MVC fails to bind the files to my object. When sending a single file, both the form and the file get correctly bound to my objects.

```
//multiple files action
public ActionResult Send(myModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
     //"model" contains the correct data
     //"files" is initialized but has Count = 0
     return View();
}

//single file action
public ActionResult SendSingle(myModel model, HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
     //"model" contains the correct data
     //"files" contains the selected file
     return View();
}
```

The `FormData` object is created by my AngularJS controller:

```
//AngularJS controller
var fData = new FormData();
fData.append("Prop1", "value1");
fData.append("Prop2", "value2");

var fileInputs = getFormFileInputs();
for (var i = 0; i < fileInputs.length; i++) {
    fData.append("files", fileInputs[i].files[0]);
}

MyService.sendData(fData);
```

The service (apparently?) sets the headers and sends the data (relevant code):

```
sendData = function(formData) {
    $q.all({
        //ResponseData: $http.post('MyController/SendSingle', formData, { 
        ResponseData: $http.post('MyController/Send', formData, { 
           transformRequest: angular.identity,
           headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        })
    }).then(...).catch(...);
}
```

What's really weird is that the `files` `IEnumerable` is instantiated but contains no files (`Count() = 0`). Inspecting the `Request` object on the server, I can see all the uploaded files inside the `Request.Files` property. The `ModelState` has an error attached to the `files` parameter, caused by an exception when trying to cast strings to `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Why isn't the server automatically binding the `files` `IEnumerable`, i.e. why isn't the server automatically binding the binary content?

**Edit:**
This seams to be a recurring topic so I'll add this information here. I've tried setting the content to `multipart/form-data`, since this is the "standard" way of posting data and files in ASP MVC. This, however, doesn't work at all: neither the form data, nor the files get automatically bound. My model properties are all `null` and the files object is also `null` (instead of initialized but with no elements). It seams that AngularJS has some problems with this content type header. On the other hand, this is the same for jQuery, where you need to set `contentType: false, processData: false` in order to post both form data and binary content.

Comment: Does it do the same thing when you check in `Request.Files` in your controller?

Comment: @Sam9291 what do you mean? I already said that I can see the uploaded files in `Request.Files`.

Comment: I doubt this line of code `fData.append("files", fileInputs[i].files[0]);`. this would work when there is a single file, but if multiple files and all are appending to same variable that might create a problem

Comment: also why `headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }` shouldn't it be : multipart/form-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tried to reproduce your problem but it works for me, so i will just post my code. I hope it helps:

html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
        <form>
            <fileupload></fileupload>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = 'World';
        });

        app.directive("fileupload", function($http) {
            return {
                replace: true,
                template: '<div><input id="file" type="file" name="img" multiple /> <button type="button" ng-click="upload()">Upload</button></div>',
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.upload = function() {
                        var data = new FormData();

                        data.append("Value", "value1");

                        for (i = 0; i < $scope.files.length; i++) {
                            data.append('files', $scope.files[i]);
                        }

                        $http.post('Home/Upload', data, {
                            transformRequest: angular.identity,
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
                        }).success(function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });;

                        console.log('upload', $scope.files);
                    };
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.find("#file").bind("change", function(changeEvent) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            scope.files = changeEvent.target.files;
                            //console.log('files', changeEvent.target.files);
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        });

    </script>
}
```

controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(TestModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        return Json(new { files = files.ToList().Select(x => x.FileName), model = model });
    }       
}
```

Comment: This is confusing... It does work but it didn't. I can't even begin to understand what was happening.

Comment: @AndreiV the mysteries of the programmers life :) sometimes happens also for me :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are unsetting the content type,  try setting it to `multipart/form-data`.  That should instruct the server how to parse the posted content.

Comment: That was the first header value I've tried. It seams the AngularJS has some issues there. Please see my edit.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using regular controller you can try to use something like this:

```
    foreach (string key in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[key];
    }
```

If you are working with WebAPI:

```
if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                var rootPath = TMP_SAVE_PATH; //some path
                var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(rootPath);

                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                foreach (var fileData in provider.FileData)
                {
                    var fileName = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\\' }).Trim(new char[] { '"' });
                    File.Move(fileData.LocalFileName, fileName); //move to some location
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but my question is not related to "how to get the files?" but rather "why isn't my `IEnumerable` correctly bound?".

Comment: In this case you can try to override a `BindModel` method of a model binder to see what is passed there. If you need the reason why the files are not bound to model you can also decompile DefaultModelBinder class. You can find more on model binding [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)